# Multidimensional array not allowing write to

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm creating a multidimensional array to look up things in a program for me. I get it to read and write properly, but once I try to alter it's values after it's read, it seems to stop working.

My read code is :

```
Arr = <Code>;(this is a part of code I have not written, but it works)
if (0f == Arr[0,0,0])
    book = true;
if (1f == Arr[0,0,1])
    video = true;
```

This part above works, I did print tests on it and they come out properly for video and books. This part also has nothing to do with my problem.

This is the part I am writing.

```
Arr[0,0,0] = 0f;
Arr[0,0,1] = 1f;
if (book == true)
    Arr[0,0,0] = 1f;
else if (video == true)
    Arr[0,0,1] = 2f;
```

I get error: IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range on line 80. Line 80 is `Arr[0,0,0] = 0;`, and the line before it calls

```
print(Arr.GetLength(0).ToString());
print(Arr.GetLength(1).ToString());
print(Arr.GetLength(2).ToString());
```

These print the correct length I am expecting for this array (3,3,5). I'm not too sure why I'm getting an indexoutofrangeexception considering I have checked the length of the array and it seems ok - I have also looked up online and yeah, this is the way to access multidimensional arrays in C#. I have done a few before, but I can't figure out why I'm getting an out of range exception on an array that is properly sized for what I am using it for.

Comment: Is this a multidimensional array, or a special class that mimicks the usage of a MD array? The reason I'm asking is, if there is a special getter/setter, the setter may just not be acting correctly due to a possible bug in the setter's code.

Comment: Try to walk through the function step by step in debugger. Does it still throw at the same line?

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you showed the declaration of Arr and how the instance is created.  For debugging, it might be interesting to see what [Arr.GetLowerBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound.aspx) reports

Comment: Another thing that you may need to consider is sync. Are there other threads that modify the array at the same time? If yes, consider access sync to the array.

Comment: It is declare at the start as float[,,] Arr = new float[3,3,5];. This is the only array modification I am calling and have created to date. This is an actual multidimensional array called Arr and not an emulated class. I've walked through it as much as I can, using GetLength and trying every spot in the array - it's like it disposes it's self, but since I call .GetLength() right before I know it's still there.

Comment: @Charles, then try to isolate the problem. Create a complete code that still exhibits the problem and post it here.

Comment: @can poyrazoglu I flagged you  as a solution because you were the closest. Apparently <Code> was silently adding a few things to the array without telling me, so I modified as required. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

First , you should know that Array is abstract class

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
```

so you can't do it like this :

```
Array arry = new Array();
```

But you can do it like this :

```
   Array[,,] arry = new Array[1,2,3];
```

Why does it works? you should pay attention to `[,,]` , you only declare a abstruct class array but haven't implement it , so it works

The following example shows how to declare a Array ,and implement it , set value to its member:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declare a int 3-dimentions array and initial its values
        int[, ,] a = new int[,,] { { { 1, 2, 3 } }, { { 2, 3, 4 } }, { { 2, 3, 4 } } };
        if (a[0, 0, 0] == 0f) //<-- It's aright
        {
            //dosomething 
        }
        ;

        a[0, 0, 0] = 20; //<it's aright too

        //declare a 3-dimentions array 
        Array[, ,] arry = new Array[1, 2, 3]; //set its value
        arry[0, 0, 0] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }; 
        arry[0, 0, 1] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
    }
```

i don't know much more about your problem base on what you have posted